# TableView frame with extra y origin in xib after setting top as translucent bar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7

TableView frame with extra y origin in `xib` after setting top as translucent bar and cannot set offset to tableview to position to y origin as 0 after `keyboardwillbehidden`.

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
self.documentdetailTable.contentInset = contentInsets;
self.documentdetailTable.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[self.documentdetailTable setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO];
```

The above is setting tableview content offset to `(0,0)` but initially it is something like `(0,64)` always,I dont know how to give offset `(0,0)`. initially table is at `(0,64,1024,800)` frame and content offset `(0,64)` by default.

Comment: Little more clarification would be useful, what do you want to do (assuming frame.origin.y = 64 and contentOffset.y = 64, you're content begins at 128? ). Where do you want your content to being?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 64 value is done automatically, by default, by the system, so your content is not below the navigation bar. If you wish to retain control over the insets yourself, add this to your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Leo Natan.. you saved me and there i am out of depression now:)

Answer (score 0):

There are two new property `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` in UIViewController since iOS7 SDK:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); // Defaults to NO, but bars are translucent by default on 7_0.  
@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0); // Defaults to YES
```

`extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` controls frameY of views in UIViewController. `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` controls contentInset of UIScrollView(contains UITableView). You could find more detail helpful information from apple's doc-set in XCode. Maybe these could help you. Good luck!